# Other ways to start a task in an asynchronous manner

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task, response

What are some other ways to create a task to begin and get a response with the same concept of  the code shown below: (Using .Net 4)

```
var uri = new Uri(website.SiteUrl);
var myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

var task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                myReq.BeginGetResponse,
                myReq.EndGetResponse,
                null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.5

```
var task = myReq.GetResponseAsync();
```

For .Net 4.0 you can write something  like this

```
public Task<HttpWebResponse> GetAsync(HttpWebRequest req)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();
    req.BeginGetResponse(e =>
        {
            if(e.IsCompleted)
                tcs.TrySetResult((HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(e));
        }, null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

But I don't see anything better than your current code.